# Widget to zoom an centre on polygon in carto db or leaflet

Tags: leaflet, cartodb

I am looking for a widget or a script example which generates a clickable list of all polygons in a layer - when a polygon in the legend is clicked, the map is panned/zoomed to that polygon.

Comment: The answer is probably [yes](http://www.strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html). Please be more specific.

Comment: As Iván says, you need to be more specific, because you are mixing several functionalities like data loading options, map state change, and UI bindings.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a specific example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say exactly what you are looking for with the little details provided in your question, but you might be interested in [Leaflet.CountrySelect](https://github.com/ahalota/Leaflet.CountrySelect/) plugin:

> Control with menu of all countries, and an event listener that returns the selected country as a GeoJSON feature ([demo](http://ahalota.github.io/Leaflet.CountrySelect/demo.html))

(although it is about "countries", it just returns whatever JavaScript object you have passed to the [`countries`](https://github.com/ahalota/Leaflet.CountrySelect/#countries) option)

You can see how it is used in the [demo source page](https://github.com/ahalota/Leaflet.CountrySelect/blob/master/demo.html), and it is also [explained](https://github.com/ahalota/Leaflet.CountrySelect/#event-listener-change) on the plugin home page.